# When stored data retrieving from coredata to tableview, the text dispalying in one cell itself, its not displaying another cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, swift3, xcode8-beta6

When stored data retrieving from `CoreData` to `tableView`, the text displaying in one cell itself, its not displaying another cell. how can I get the text in individual cells.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasks.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = task.name
        return cell
    }
    func getData()
    {
      let context =  (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        do{
        tasks = try context.fetch(Task.fetchRequest())
        }catch{
            print("fetching error")
        }
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        getData()

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

[image: simulator]

Comment: Is `getData` method retrieving the `tasks` from the server or from `CoreData`?

Comment: getData retrieving form coreData

Comment: what is the count of the `tasks` array?

Comment: var tasks: [Task] = [ ].... I have given tasks.count

Comment: But when you use the debugger, what is the actual value with your test data?